# Why I am getting error while performing group by in hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am executing below command in hive:

```
Select child.data_volume_gprs_dl + child.data_volume_gprs_ul as data_usage,
       parent.file_name,
       parent.record_number
  from table1 as parent
  left join table2 child
    on parent.file_name = child.file_name
   and parent.record_number = child.record_number
 where parent.served_imsi like '310120%'
    or parent.served_imsi like '312530%'
   and parent.serving_node_plmn_id like '310260%'
   and parent.date_part = 20191201
 group by parent.file_name, parent.record_number
```

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException
>   [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key
>   'data_volume_gprs_dl' (state=42000,code=10025)

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Clearly, your query is not valid SQL, so it doesn't do a good job describing the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All non-aggregated columns should be in the `GROUP BY` list such as

```
 group by parent.file_name, parent.record_number,
          child.data_volume_gprs_dl, child.data_volume_gprs_ul
```

If you need to group by `parent.file_name` and `parent.record_number` columns only, then you can apply aggregation ( `sum()`, `avg()`, `count()` ) functions for the rest of the columns. Even addition `sum(child.data_volume_gprs_dl + child.data_volume_gprs_ul)` might be possible.

Comment: But my requirement is to group by on parent.file_name, parent.record_number. Is there any alternate way for this.